# Why map transforms in object in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, mongodb, object

I had a problem.

When i create map in MongoDB
Example Shop

```js
        guildID: id,
        ownerID: owner_id,
        _premium: 0,
        Moderation:{
            auto:false,
            prefix:'k!',
            muterole:0,
            language: preferredLocale
        },
        Economy: {
            shop:new Map(),
            upXP:100,
            bonus:50,
            money:3,
            xp:5
        },
        options:{
            boxes:false
        }
```

Its create a object

[image]

How to fix it?
I use MongoDB(not mongoose)

Comment: MongoDB uses [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) serializer and it [does not support](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/4613763/src/parser/serializer.ts#L843) Map objects per se.

Comment: @aleksxor And what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is MongoDB uses [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) format for storing documents. And it [does not support](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/4613763/src/parser/serializer.ts#L843) Map objects now. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/pull/253) to to add functionality close to what you're looking for. But as for now it's not implemented.

You may write your own deserializer to restore your Map object. After getting the document from the DB you'll have to transfrom certain properties into corresponding entities. Map in your case. Something like:

```ts
class Economy {
  
    deserialize(data) {
        ...
        this.shop = new Map<string, Shop>(Object.entries(data.shop));
        ...
    }
}
```